# qemu/kvm snapshot with non-usb device

Tags: qemu, pci, snapshot

I have a fully-working QEMU virtual machine (ubutu host, XP guest). I cannot save the machine state into a snapshot because I have a PCIe card attached to the VM. The error message says «Requested operation is not valid: domain has assigned non-USB host devices». The “non-USB device” is the PCIe card. When I detach it from the VM, the snapshot works flawlessly. The reason for the error is (I suppose) that the PCIe card may suffer changes between the creation and the restoring of the snapshot, so this is disabled by default.

Is there a way around this? I absolutely need the PCIe card on the XP guest, and I have actually detached it from the host, so the host never uses it. But I’d like to be able to use snapshots on the VM, as my work involves working with several different programs in XP.

Answer (score 1):

Can you: 
grep -i denied on /var/log/kern.log 
It might be apparmor blocking it. If yes, then you modify the apparmor acl for libvirt-qemu.

Best.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I have indeed found several instances of «apparmor="DENIED"» inside /var/log/kern.log. So you might be right about apparmor blocking what I want to do. However, I don’t know exactly what you mean by «modify the apparmor acl for libvirt-qemu». I‘ve found a folder called ‘apparmor’ in /etc. I suppose you mean I could add a line to some file in it; but what should that line be, what file, and at what point in the file? Could you help me on that?

Comment: What exactly does the apparmor message say? Also, which version of libvirt are you using? Try to get the latest apparmor profile for libvirt. For PCIe emulation use q35 - https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/Q35